# How to ignore all errors in Acumatica updater

Tags: acumatica

I've executed update of Acumatica data base and faced following error messages:

[image]

For now I'd like to ignore all errors during update. Is there a way automatically to ignore all error messages during update of Acumatica database?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to ignore database errors as far as I know, but the error you are seeing seems related to temporary keys.

You could try to optimize the database before upgrading by going to `SYSTEM->MANAGEMENT->MANAGE->Companies`, selecting your company and clicking on "OPTIMIZE DATABASE".

[image: Optimize Company DB]

Another option would be to temporarily disable constraints on the table that triggers the errors but I would test this before trying it on a production environment and you need to enable (rebuild) the index once you are done.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/disable-indexes-and-constraints

Comment: Cool, now I know what is purpose of Optimize database button

Comment: I wonder if using the Acumatica configuration wizard (Perform Database Maintenance) to "Repair" a DB would also solve this (as an alternative to Optimize database?)

Comment: Hi, @YuraZaletskyy , did this answer your question? If so, could you accept it as a correct answer? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately it absolutely not helpful in mine case. It's good idea, but didn't work. That's why I voted up your answer but can't accept something that didn't work.

Comment: I understand, thank you. And did you find a solution to your problem?